# Create a link to controller function and redirect to another page with ID

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to update a notification counter. that counter is the sum of 'unread' columns so let say the user has 5 unread post. My logic is if the user click the button, he/she will be pointed to a controller to update the record, in my case, ReportsController@updateSu

so i have this in my route,

```
Route::get('reports/updateSu/{id}', 'ReportsController@updateSu')
       ->name('reports.updateSu');
```

and here's my button

```
<form action="{{ route('reports.updateSu', $payment->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('put') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="setDelivered" value="4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
</form>
```

after to run the update, I want to redirect the user to this page, `/salesPayments/{id}/edit`

Here's what I tried so far,

```
public function updateSu($id)
{
    // ---- do some updates here ---
    return redirect()->route('salesPayments',$id,'edit');
}
```

How Can I properly do it here in laravel? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a variable to point to route you want

```
$route = "/salesPayments/$id/edit"
```

then use `redirect` function with the route

```
public function updateSu($id)
{
    // ---- do some updates here ---
    $route = "/salesPayments/$id/edit"
    return redirect($route);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ali i have a felling my form action route is not reaching my controll, action="{{ route('reports.updateSu', $payment->id)}}"   . again my route is Route::get('reports/{id}/updateSu', 'ReportsController@updateSu')->name('reports.updateSu'); are they both ok?

Comment: yeah , I thought so , because in your route you listen to `GET` request and in your form you set it to `PUT` request

Comment: oh man thanks that's so careless of me! I stare at them for a long time haven't notice the form method hahaha thank you so much @Ali!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the function points to the edit link

return redirect()->route('salesPayments', $id);